# cellRendererFramework no component factory found ag-grid angular2

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

Trying to use cellRendererFramework(v13.1.2) with angular2 but getting this error instead:

**ProductComponentComponent.html:7 ERROR Error: No component factory found for [object Object]. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
    at noComponentFactoryError (core.es5.js:3202)**

Is cellRendererFramework not supported in ag-grid v13.1.2? Or is there some other issue.

Something similar has been asked earlier but didn't found any helpful answer.Please help with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No component factory found. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45412915/no-component-factory-found-did-you-add-it-to-ngmodule-entrycomponents)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did. ( Version 19.1.1).

In `app.module.ts`, Import your renderers with `AgGridModule.withComponents` as

```
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
         ...
           AgGridModule.withComponents([
              ActionRendererComponent,
              YesnoRendererComponent, 
              StatusRendererComponent
          ])
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

I added the component to the @NgModule's entryComponents, as the error message points to. For example...

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    ...
],
declarations: [
    ...
    myRendererComponent,
    ...
],
providers: [
    ...
],
entryComponents: [
    myRendererComponent
]
```

See https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2017/02/12/angular2-error-no-component-factory-found-did-you-add-it-to-ngmodule-entrycomponents/

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit late but I ended up here while having the same issue.
Here is how I fixed it, in the grid options:

```
this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
  ...
  frameworkComponents: {
    "checkboxRenderer": CheckboxCellRendererComponent
  }
}
```

then in the column defs:

```
{
  field: "present",
  headerName: "User was present",
  cellRenderer: "checkboxRenderer"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the above two solutions are not working then it is highly likely that you are passing `string` to `ComponentFactoryResolver` when loading data from server but it should be component type.

Check this url : [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45412915/no-component-factory-found-did-you-add-it-to-ngmodule-entrycomponents?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things as mentioned in previous answers, I got it working by doing couple of things.

in module definition, add your renderer for both `declarations` and `entryComponents`.

```

```
declarations: [ReportHyperlinkCellRenderer],
entryComponents: [ReportHyperlinkCellRenderer],
```

```

define your `GridOptions` as

```

```
{
  frameworkComponents: {
    "hyperlinkRenderer": ReportHyperlinkCellRenderer
  }
}
```

```

afterwards, your `ColDef` can be just simple as

```

```
{
  cellRenderer: "hyperlinkRenderer"
}
```

```