# Angular 4: no component factory found,did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Tags: angular, angular-webpack-starter

I'm using Angular 4 template with webpack
and I have this error when I try to use a component (ConfirmComponent):

> No component factory found for ConfirmComponent.  Did you add it to
>   @NgModule.entryComponents?

The component is declared in `app.module.server.ts`

```js
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  imports: [
    // ...
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    ConfirmComponent,
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I have also  `app.module.browser.ts` and `app.module.shared.ts`

How can I fix that?

Comment: How are you using `ConfirmComponent` the details are not enough to answer your question

Comment: Hi.i'm using it after imprting in my component   import { ConfirmComponent } from "../confirm.component/confirm.component";

Comment: read here about entry components [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e)

Comment: If it is going to act as a common component you can put it into CommonModule's declarations and entryComponents, and remove from other places.

Comment: @CodeSpy the solution in the above link worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 544, accepted):

Add this in your `module.ts`,

```js
declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  ConfirmComponent
]
```

if ConfirmComponent is in another module, you need to export it there thus you can use it outside, add:

```js
exports: [ ConfirmComponent ]
```

**---Update Angular 9 or  Angular 8 with Ivy explicitly enabled---**

*Entry Components With Ivy are not required anymore and now are deprecated*

**---for Angular 9 and 8  with Ivy disabled---**

In the case of a dynamically loaded component and in order for a ComponentFactory to be generated, the component must also be added to the module’s entryComponents:

```js
declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  ConfirmComponent
],
entryComponents: [ConfirmComponent],
```

according to the definition of entryComponents

> Specifies a list of components that should be compiled when this module is defined. For each component listed here, Angular will create a ComponentFactory and store it in the ComponentFactoryResolver.

Comment: Hi.it is already in app.module.shared.ts and  entryComponents is in app.module.server.ts

Comment: if ConfirmComponent is in another module, you need to export it there thus you can use it outside, add : exports: [ ConfirmComponent ] in your app.module.shared.ts

Comment: it is the ng2-bootstrap-modal component from    https://github.com/ankosoftware/ng2-bootstrap-modal/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thanks to all of you.!!!!!!!..putting all declarations and entryComponents in the same file app.module.shared.ts fixed the problem

Comment: Please edit the content of comments into the answer.

Comment: exports not working ... entryComponents option working for me !.

Comment: This solved my problem with `ng-bootstrap` and `NgModal` service using components.

Comment: this solution help me again. i forget to add it to app.module. why it cant detect like ionic generate page command and prompt us

Comment: entryComponents: [COMPONENTWITHISSUE] did it for me!

Comment: Mine is a lazy loaded module and `entryComponents` worked for me.

Comment: my component which calls **ModalComponent** is a grandchild of a component. Neither adding the **ModalComponent** to `entryComponents` nor adding it to `exports` worked for me. **BUT** I can call the **ModalComponent** from some other components which are not grandchilds

Comment: I did in the specific module but it didn't work for me. in my case i have a lazy loading module that is : DashboardModule and i put the component in the entry components  and in the declarations part but it throws the same error :( idk what is missing help me please

Answer (score 158):

[See the details](https://angular.io/guide/entry-components#the-entrycomponents-array) about `entryComponent`:

If you are loading any component dynamically then you need to put it in both `declarations` and `entryComponent`:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  exports: [...],
  entryComponents: [ConfirmComponent,..],
  declarations: [ConfirmComponent,...],
  providers: [...]
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I mean, THANKS!!! I was creating a dialog to enter data inside another component (The dialog has its component declaration inside the other component, and dialog.html for the layout)

Comment: This did the trick for me and also has a better explanation than the chosen answer. Thank you!

Comment: Clearly the best answer for me!

Comment: This was the solution for me; I was creating a component on the fly and had everything in the correct modules but was still getting the error. Adding my created components to `entryComponents` was the solution - thank you!

Comment: my component which calls **ModalComponent** is a grandchild of a component. Neither adding the **ModalComponent** to `entryComponents` nor adding it to `exports` worked for me. **BUT** I can call the **ModalComponent** from some other components which are not grandchilds

Comment: @canbax I solved the same problem by using `imports:[..., ModalModule.forRoot()]` instead of `imports:[..., ModalModule]` in my app.module.ts

Comment: Mr Mohamed's answer might have been 'slightly' long winded, but nevertheless had everything you needed to know.

Answer (score 67):

TL;DR: A service in ng6 with `providedIn: "root"` cannot find the ComponentFactory when the Component is not added in the `entryComponents` of *app.module*.

This problem can also occur if you are using angular 6 in combination with dynamically creating a Component in a service!

For example, creating an Overlay:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class OverlayService {

  constructor(private _overlay: Overlay) {}

  openOverlay() {
    const overlayRef = this._createOverlay();
    const portal = new ComponentPortal(OverlayExampleComponent);

    overlayRef.attach(portal).instance;
  }
}
```

The Problem is the

> providedIn: "root"

definition, which provides this service in *app.module*.

So if your service is located in, for example, the "OverlayModule", where you also declared the OverlayExampleComponent and added it to the entryComponents, the service cannot find the ComponentFactory for OverlayExampleComponent.

Comment: Problem specific to Angular 6. Fix the problem by adding your component to entryComponents in @NgModule 

    @NgModule({ 
      entryComponents:[ 
        yourComponentName 
      ]
    })

Comment: This can be fixed by removing `providedIn` and instead using the `providers` option on the module.

Comment: Thanks for info, but it adding to @NgModule({ ... , entryComponents:[...] }) worked for me even with providedIn: "root"

Comment: this seems related to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14324
it seems will be solved in Angular 9

Comment: Exactly, especially in lazy-loaded module. To fix this, I specified NgModule.providers: [MyLazyLoadedModuleService] and changed MyLazyLoadedModuleService.providedIn from "root" to MyLazyLoadedmodule.

Answer (score 55):

I had the same issue. In this case `imports [...]` is crucial, because it won't work if you don't import `NgbModalModule`.

Error description says that components should be added to `entryComponents` array and it is obvious, but make sure you have added this one in the first place:

```
imports: [
    ...
    NgbModalModule,
    ...
  ],
```

Comment: You saved me, cheers! This is definetely required when you try to open component in a modal. The error message is a bit misleading in this situation.

Comment: Where do you import it from?

Comment: In my case changed import of NbDialogModule to NbDialogModule.forChild(null),

Comment: @Mdomin45 import { NgbModalModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

Comment: This also helped me. Tried adding declarations and entry components to no luck. And yes, the error is misleading in this case.

Comment: I did this on Angular 8 and I got a lot of errors after running the app.

Answer (score 26):

Add that component to entryComponents in @NgModule of your app's module:

```
entryComponents:[ConfirmComponent],
```

as well as Declarations:

```
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ConfirmComponent
]
```

Comment: Saved my day! Cheers mate

Comment: my component which calls **ModalComponent** is a grandchild of a component. Neither adding the **ModalComponent** to `entryComponents` nor adding it to `exports` worked for me. **BUT** I can call the **ModalComponent** from some other components which are not grandchilds

Answer (score 15):

Add 'NgbModalModule' in imports and your component name in entryComponents App.module.ts as shown below
[image]

Comment: my component which calls **ModalComponent** is a grandchild of a component. Neither adding the **ModalComponent** to `entryComponents` nor adding it to `exports` worked for me. **BUT** I can call the **ModalComponent** from some other components which are not grandchilds

Comment: I need to re iterate this answer, if your component has been added to entryComponents already, and you're still experiencing the problem, make sure to check the modalComponent you're using and add it on the imports array! This saved my life!

Answer (score 10):

I have the same problem with angular 6, 
that's what worked for me :

```
@NgModule({
...
entryComponents: [ConfirmComponent],
providers:[ConfirmService]

})
```

If you have a service like **ConfirmService**, have to be declare in providers of current module instead of *root*

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue for bootstrap modal

> import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

If this is your case just add the component to the module declarations and entryComponents as other responses suggest, but also add this to your module

> import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

```
imports: [
   NgbModule.forRoot(),
   ...
]
```

Answer (score 8):

I had same issue in Angular7 when I create dynamic components. There are two components(TreatListComponent, MyTreatComponent) that needs to be loaded dynamically. I just added entryComponents array in to my app.module.ts file.

```
    entryComponents: [
    TreatListComponent,
    MyTreatComponent
  ],
```

Answer (score 8):

This error occur when you try to load a component dynamically and:

1. The component you want to load is not routing module
2. The component is no in module entryComponents.

in routingModule

```
const routes: Routes = [{ path: 'confirm-component', component: ConfirmComponent,data: {}}]
```

or in module

```
entryComponents: [
ConfirmComponent
}
```

To fix this error you can add a router to the component or add it to entryComponents of module.

1. Add a router to component.drawback of this approach is your
   component will be accessible with that url.
2. Add it to entryComponents. in this case your component will not have any url attached to and it will not be accessible with url.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I forgot to add `MatDialogModule` to imports in a child module.

Comment: Lifesaver! I had done what everyone else suggested and was still getting the error. After countless hours of trying, I saw your post and it fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

**if you use routing in your application**

> **make sure Add new components into the routing path**

for example :

```
    const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'fundList',      component: FundListComponent },
];
```

Comment: No, I don't think every component should be in a route.

Comment: Only the pages you want to display should be in routes. A page can use/display multiple components

Comment: every time you dont need to add component in to Route, such as modals.                Place components which are created dynamically to entryComponents under @NgModuledecorator function.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I didn't need entryComponents at all - just the basic setup as described in the link below, but I needed to include the import in both the main app module and the enclosing module.

```
imports: [
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    ...
]
```

https://medium.com/@sunilk/getting-started-angular-6-and-ng-bootstrap-4-4b314e015c1c

You only need to add it to entryComponents if a component will be included in the modal. From the docs:

> You can pass an existing component as content of the modal window. In
>   this case remember to add content component as an entryComponents
>   section of your NgModule.

Comment: `error TS2339: Property 'forRoot' does not exist on type 'typeof NgbModule'.` using angular 8

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same issue with ag-grid using dynamic components. I discovered you need to add the dynamic component to the ag-grid module .withComponents[]

imports: [
    StratoMaterialModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    **AgGridModule.withComponents(ProjectUpdateButtonComponent)**
  ],

Answer (score 3):

1. `entryComponents` is vital. Above answers on this are correct.

But...

2. If you're providing a service that opens the modal (a common pattern) 
   and your module that defines the dialog component is not loaded in AppModule, you need to change `providedIn: 'root'` to `providedIn: MyModule`.  As general good practice you should just use the `providedIn: SomeModule` for all dialog services that are in modules.

Answer (score 3):

You should import the `NgbModule` in the **module** like this:

```html
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AboutModalComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    RouterModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgxLoadingModule,
    NgbDatepickerModule,
    NgbModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [AboutModalComponent]
})
 export class HomeModule {}
```

Comment: Perfect for that bro
the example url -- https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2017/02/12/angular2-error-no-component-factory-found-did-you-add-it-to-ngmodule-entrycomponents/

Answer (score 2):

For clarification here. In case you are not using `ComponentFactoryResolver` directly in component, and you want to abstract it to service, which is then injected into component you have to load it under providers for that module, since if lazy loaded it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

In case you have still the error after providing component dialog class in `entryComponents`, try to restart `ng serve` - it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

My error was calling NgbModal open method with incorrect parameters from .html

Answer (score 2):

i import the material design dialog module , so i created aboutcomponent for dialog the call this component from openDialog method then i got this error , i just put this

```
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ExampleDialogComponent
  ],

  entryComponents: [
    ExampleDialogComponent
  ],
```

Comment: This fixed my issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Angular8, and I'm trying to ***open the component dynamically form another module***, 
In this case, you need to `import the module` into the module that's trying to open the component, **of course in addition to** `export` the component and list it into the `entryComponents` array as the previous answers did.

```
imports: [
    ...
    TheModuleThatOwnTheTargetedComponent,
    ...
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i solved this issue by:
1) placing `NgxMaterialTimepickerModule` in `app module imports:[ ]`
2) placing `NgxMaterialTimepickerModule` in `testmodule.ts imports:[ ]`
3) placing `testcomponent` in `declartions:[ ]` and `entryComponents:[ ]`

(I'm using angular 8+ version)

Answer (score 0):

If you still haven't resolved this issue - like me - here is what caused this error for me. As @jkyoutsey suggested, I was indeed trying to create a modal component. I spent considerable time following his suggestions by moving my component to a service and injecting it into the page component. Also changing providedIn: 'root' to MyModule, which of course had to be moved at least one level up to avoid a circular reference. I'm not all together sure any of that actually was necessary.

What finally solved the 8-hour long puzzle was to **NOT implement ngOnInit** in my component. I had blindly implemented ngOnInit even though the function was empty. I tend to do that. It's probably a bad practice.

Anyway, if someone could shed light on why an empty ngOnInit would have caused this error, I'd love to read the comments.

Answer (score 0):

In this section, you must enter the component that is used as a child in addition to `declarations: [CityModalComponent]`(modal components) in the following section in the `app.module.ts` file:

```
 entryComponents: [
CityModalComponent
],
```

Answer (score -2):

I might be replying late on this. But removing this can be helpful for some people who are still looking for solutions to this problem and has this in their code. We had below entry since long in our tsconfig.json file:

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }
```

We also face same problem. After lot of experiments, we removed this block from tsconfig.json. Now our code is not complaining this problem anymore.

Comment: had to scroll too far for this, but this solves the issue!

Comment: I get the error even without having `angularCompilerOptions` in tsconfig.json file.