# Angular2 Universal Server side rendering NgbTypeaheadWindow Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents

Tags: angular, webpack, angular5, angular2-directives, angular-universal

i'm moving my project to angular universal due an SEO improvments.
i followed this guide:
(im using angular version 5)
 https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering
and finally, after rendering the server and the client side, 
when i try hit node dist/server.js 
its failed , and pop me up the msg below:

[image here click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xNEp.png)

i tried almsot everything, move the NgbTypeaheadWindow to a SharedModule.

first tried:

adding to app.module.ts like the error suggested

```
import { NgbTypeaheadWindow } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/typeahead/typeahead-window';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
         /** others modules/**
        SharedModule,
        NgbTypeaheadWindow
    ],

    entryComponents: [NgbTypeaheadWindow]
```

but still not working.

getting this error:

> ERROR in : Unexpected directive 'NgbTypeaheadWindow in
>   C:/Users/benn/Documents/dev/angular_universal_without_e2e/client/node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/typeahead/typeahead-window.d.ts'
>   imported by the module 'AppModule in
>   C:/Users/benn/Documents/dev/angular_universal_without_e2e/client/src/app/app.module.ts'.
>   Please add a @NgModule annotation.

So, i tried add it also to declarations and then export it like this post suggest:

[Angular 4: no component factory found,did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46990389/angular-4-no-component-factory-found-did-you-add-it-to-ngmodule-entrycomponent):

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NgbTypeaheadWindow
    ],
    imports: [
        SharedModule,
    ]

    entryComponents: [NgbTypeaheadWindow],
    exports:[NgbTypeaheadWindow]
```

and get this error:

> ERROR in : Type NgbTypeaheadWindow in C:/Users/benn/Documents/dev/angular_universal_without_e2e/client/node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/typeahead/typeahead-window.d.ts is part of the declarations of
>   2 modules: NgbTypeaheadModule in C:/Users/benn/Documents/dev/angular_universal_without_e2e/client/node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/typeahead/typeahead.module.d.ts and AppModule in C:/Users/benn/Documents/dev/angular_universal_without_e2e/client/src/app/app.module.ts! Please consider moving NgbTypeaheadWindow in C:/Users/benn/Documents/dev/angular_universal_without_e2e/client/node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/typeahead/typeahead-window.d.ts to a higher module that imports NgbTypeaheadModule in C:/Users/benn/Documents/dev/angular_universal_without_e2e/client/node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/typeahead/typeahead.module.d.ts and AppModule in C:/Users/benn/Documents/dev/angular_universal_without_e2e/client/src/app/app.module.ts. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes NgbTypeaheadWindow in C:/Users/benn/Documents/dev/angular_universal_without_e2e/client/node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/typeahead/typeahead-window.d.ts then import that NgModule in NgbTypeaheadModule in C:/Users/benn/Documents/dev/angular_universal_without_e2e/client/node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/typeahead/typeahead.module.d.ts and AppModule in C:/Users/benn/Documents/dev/angular_universal_without_e2e/client/src/app/app.module.ts.

after that, i tried to move it to my SharedModule but still.

here is my SharedModule :

```
import { NgbTypeaheadWindow } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/typeahead/typeahead-window';

        @NgModule({
      imports: [CommonModule,NgbTypeaheadWindow],
      declarations: [CaruselComponent],
      exports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, CaruselComponent,NgbTypeaheadWindow],

    })
    export class SharedModule { }
```

> ERROR in : Unexpected directive 'NgbTypeaheadWindow in
>   C:/Users/benn/Documents/dev/angular_universal_without_e2e/client/node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/typeahead/typeahead-window.d.ts'
>   imported by the module 'SharedModule in
>   C:/Users/benn/Documents/dev/angular_universal_without_e2e/client/src/app/shared/shared.module.ts'.
>   Please add a @NgModule annotation.

i tried it to app.server.module.ts but still.

Hope you can help
thanks

Comment: why are you trying to import it at the first place? its a directive and it comes as a part of the typeahead module.

Comment: which  version of ng boostrap are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by not choose to render it on serverside with IsPlatFormServer and isPlatFormBrowser

Answer (score 0):

Import the NgbTypeaheadModule instead of the directives/components related to it.

import { NgbTypeaheadModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/typeahead';

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
         /** others modules/**
        SharedModule,
        NgbTypeaheadModule
    ],
    entryComponents: []
})
```

Comment: added to app.module.ts , import NgbTypeaheadModule from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap' , and added to imports: [    NgbTypeaheadModule,..] still got the same Error: No component factory found for NgbTypeaheadWindow. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Comment: dont add it to your imports, if its in your app.module.ts