# angular 5 dynamic component no component factory found

Tags: angular, angular-webpack

I'm using this SO answer to create dynamic tabs:

[Angular dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)

I'm getting this error:

```
No component factory found for C1. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

There is a page on SO which suggests how to fix this problem:

[Angular 4: no component factory found,did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46990389/angular-4-no-component-factory-found-did-you-add-it-to-ngmodule-entrycomponent)

I've tried the proposed solutions there and I can't get rid of this error.

My application is structured with submodules, which I think might have something to do with why this solution doesn't work.  Here is what I've tried specifically:

- Added C1 to both "declarations" and "entryComponents" in my submodule
- Exported C1 from the submodule, imported the submodule into app.module, and added C1 to both "declarations and "entryComponents" in my app.module

Neither of these work.  Any suggestions on what I could try now or maybe some suggestions on how to get specific information on what is actually failing?

Comment: You put this component in declarations and exports of his father module ?

Comment: I tried both ways - putting declarations and entryComponents into the module that contains all the code (which I believe is lazy loaded).  I also tried exporting from module that contains all the code (so that app.module could see the components) and adding entryComponents to app.module.  Neither works.