# How to implement a Ionic modal within a service that is available in all modules (pages) where the service is available?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular8

I have a secondary module of the AppModule, in this case, it is called DriverModule, and within that module, I have the DriversService service added within the providers array. Within the DriversModule, I have children routes that I charge using lazy modules.

The service works well within all pages under DirverModule.

My problem is when I try to put a modal into that service that is running on all the daughter pages of DriversModule, I get this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for ServiceOfferingComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
Error: No component factory found for ServiceOfferingComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
    at noComponentFactoryError
```

Even though I already put the component inside the declarations and entryComponents arrays.

```
import { ServiceOfferingComponent } from './service-offering/service-offering.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ServiceOfferingComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  providers: [
    DriverService,
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    ServiceOfferingComponent
  ]
})
export class DriverModule { }
```

```
import { ServiceOfferingComponent } from './service-offering/service-offering.component';


import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Injectable()
export class DriverService {

constructor(
    public modalController: ModalController
  ) { 
    someObservable$.subscription((val:boolean) =>{
        if(val) this.showServiceOfferingModal();
    });
 }

async showServiceOfferingModal() {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: ServiceOfferingComponent,
      backdropDismiss: false
    });
    await modal.present();
  }

}
```

My assumption is that if the service works well within all the daughter routes of DriversModule I can present the modal on the current daughter page, no matter on which daughter page of the DriversModule I am browsing as long as the service is available. But apparently, that assumption is incorrect.

**Do you know any technique to put a modal into a service and when a condition arises, present the modal on the page that the user is browsing, regardless of which page it is as long as it is the daughter page of the DriversModule?**

Comment: Can you remove the call to `showServiceOfferingModal()` in the constructor and call it from a components `ngOnInit`? I suspect that the reason you get this error is because the component is not ready when the `DriverService` is instantiated

Comment: Also check if this answer is relevant in your case https://stackoverflow.com/a/51831884/5253155

Comment: I already tried, I even tried it on the `ionViewDidEnter()` and neither, I think it is impossible to achieve put a modal into a service.